# Webpack : Bundle to cjs or esm formats

Tags: webpack, rollupjs

Can I bundle Javascript files as cjs or esm formats using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)

I know [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) can do it but I have a project already configured with Webpack and I want to bundle it to cjs or esm formats.

I read this article and I can't figure out if it possible or not

https://thedrearlight.com/blog/delivering-js-modules.html